# Video Download problem for download manager in 9.10

Tags: video, 9.10, downloads

My requirement is to download various videos from different websites :

1. Youtube
2. Meta cafe
3. Vimeo
4. Others

No matter what download manager I use :

1. Kget
2. Uget
3. Downloader for X

videos are not able to download only some strange "Watch" file of some kb size is downloaded.

" I COPY AND PASTE THE URL OF THE VIDEO TO THE "

My system is UBUNTU 9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an extension that is in Firefox. It's called Downloadhelper it downloads videos for all of those websites and more.